# Magento 2 : Adding Custom Attribute "color" to Order Items in Backend

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, sales-order, items

How do I add custom attribute "color". I have made to order items in backend.

I have tried:

- $_item->getColor()
- $_item->getAttributes()
- $_item->getAttribute('color')

And a bunch of other stuff:

`vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\items\column\name.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @see \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name
 */
?>

<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('SKU') ?>:</span> <?php echo implode('<br />', $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))); ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option['value']; ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid()?>"> ...</span><span id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id = 'id' . uniqid()?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dots?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dots ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item object has a product property that you can retrieve by

```
       `$product = $_item->getProduct();
        $color = $product->getData('color');
```

Make sure that $_item is instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item`

Comment: As a one-liner: $_item->getProduct()->getData('color');

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());

$color = $product->getAttributeText('color');
```

Comment: Do not use object manager directly in your code. instead of this use DI

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. 
for get value from drop-down attribute:

```
$color = $product->getAttributeText('color');
```

instead of:

```
$color = $product->getData('color');
```